# Configuring startup apps during ISO customization in UCK

Tags: 16.04, autostart, uck

I would like to customize ubuntu image that would have pre-configured autostartup. In general, user goes to "Startup Applications" GUI and adds a specific command to be run on the start up. The [answer in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) points out the the /home/user/.config/autostart directory. I assume I can simply add files there with the content like below that would execute on startup.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "sudo /home/user/bin/myScript.sh"
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=MY APP
Name=MY APP
Comment[en EN]=
Comment=
```

Using this approach, I would like to add the startup files to the ISO image "opened" by UCK into the remaster-root/home/user/.config/autostart directory, but it does not exist for obvious reasons - the user has not been created yet (this only happens on the installation boot?).

Is there an alternative way to pre-configure the ISO image, so after installation the script runs on system startup?

Comment: I believe you put them in the `remaster-root/etc/skel/.config/autostart/` folder as `/etc/skel/` is the default user that is loaded when the ISO boots.

Comment: makes sense. I will give it a try and let you know

Comment: @Terrance Yep, that works!

Comment: You're welcome!  Posted it as an answer for you.  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts that you wanted started in a custom ISO, you put in the following folder:

```
remaster-root/etc/skel/.config/autostart/
```

as when the ISO boots the `/etc/skel/` folder becomes the default user.  There is where you can also put desktop icons and shortcuts or other scripts that you want.

Hope this helps!